# Java: what type should I use as a resizable list of primitives?

Tags: java, arraylist, primitive, resizable

I would like to have an object that is a resizable list of `byte`s that implements the following interface:

- get current size
- clear the list (reset size to zero)
- add a `byte` to the end
- remove a`byte` from the end
- get value of any element by index

Also it is known that this list never need hold more than 21 elements.

I have already implemented this object as just an array, `byte[]` of size 21, and an `int` that gives the index of the next not-yet-populated element, and had great success using it.

This seems like a simple implementation but doesn't java have build-in type for this kind of thing already? I imagine the need for such a thing is extremely prevelant. I tried using a `ArrayList<Byte>` but it is super slow and my runtime scales exponentially with iterations. Am I suffering from boxing/unboxing performance losses? Which built-in type should I use as my resizable list of primatives?

Comment: what about `LinkedList<Byte>`? it is the best option for first four clauses

Comment: @AndrewTobilko: If `ArrayList<Byte>` is "super slow" in their use case, I can't see `LinkedList<Byte>` being much, if any, better.

Comment: What's your motivation for making a change? If you have something that works well for your scenario and you already know that `ArrayList<Byte>` doesn't suit...?

Comment: If you only add and remove elements at the end `ArrayList` should be the best option. What makes you think it is "super slow" as compared to manually handling an array? Did you profile your code? Is there any chance you recreate lists instead of reusing them?

Comment: You could use a [`java.nio.ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

Comment: `ArrayList` amortized cost of appending at the end is more than outeweighed by its `O(1)` indexed access, compared to `LinkedList`'s O(n)

Comment: I haven't tried, but [eclipse collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) has some native collections. I am surprised by the lack of a list for native elements. I also wrote my own version of an ArrayList using int's, called an IntList, due to performance issues. Sometimes the boxing/unboxing can have serious performance issues.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko actually the first 4 points are equally well supported by `ArrayList` if the maximum size is known since they are all O(1). The problem, however, might be that neither of the built-in collections can handle primitives so you'd either have to use specialized primitive collections (AFAIK Apache Commons Collections has some) or use primitive wrappers and thus (un)boxing which can cost some performance.

Comment: @schwobaseggl, `LinkedList` appends at the end by `O(1)`, doesn't it?

Comment: @schwobaseggl if the arraylist is initialized with the maximum capacity of 21 even appending at the end should be O(1) (it effectively amounts to `elementData[size++] = e;`).

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yes, it does, but so does `ArrayList` (amortized or with predefined capacity). Adding and removing at the beginning is where the `LinkedList` really beats `ArrayList`

Comment: @Thomas Yep, absolutely. It was more of a general note.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko LinkedList is terrible. Forget about it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is it not always better to use built in libraries instead of something you implemented yourself, even if it works?

Comment: @schwobaseggl if I know the maximum capacity needed for an `ArrayList` at construction time, and I create the `ArrayList` with this initial capacity, can't I add and remove elements from the end of the `ArrayList` in O(1)?

Answer (score 2):

If an external library is allowed, you can use [HPPC](https://labs.carrotsearch.com/hppc.html) (High Performance Primitive Collections for Java). It support **Lists, Sets and Maps of all Java primitives.**

You will have to make a compromise when dealing with those requirements. I recommend finding the most used operation, and choose the support structure based on that.

Comment: fastutil is better.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already said, standard Java doesn't support primitive collections.  If you are open to a third party library, [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) [`MutableByteList`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/primitive/MutableByteList.html) will support the list of requirements you have specified.

```
MutableByteList byteList = ByteLists.mutable.empty();
Assert.assertEquals(0, byteList.size());
byteList.add((byte) 1);
byteList.add((byte) 2);
byteList.add((byte) 3);
Assert.assertEquals(3, byteList.size());
byteList.removeAtIndex(2);
Assert.assertEquals(
    ByteLists.mutable.with((byte) 1, (byte) 2), byteList);
byteList.addAtIndex(2, (byte) 3);
Assert.assertEquals(
    ByteLists.mutable.with((byte) 1, (byte) 2, (byte) 3), byteList);
Assert.assertTrue((byte) 2 == byteList.get(1));
byteList.clear();
Assert.assertEquals(0, byteList.size());
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 0):

Standard Java does not offer collections for any of the primitive types.

But the compiler does a lot of auto-boxing for you; and there are nice helper methods, so going forward from `byte[]` to `List<Byte>` is probably not much work **coding wise**.

But it seems you hit the the big problem with such code: it comes with performance cost. But this can't be assessed by talking about it on such a generic level.

Long story short: if your environment allows you to turn to one of the recommend 3rd party libraries ... just try them. If not, you have to understand where your CPU cycles are coming from:

a) by profiling

or

b) by extensive review (if you have some sharp-eyed coworkers around - show them your code; and then you try to figure where (un)boxing takes place; and how to avoid it)

If the "internal review" doesn't work for you, you can turn to codereview.stackexchange.com